# convert html page to image html2image

Tags: html, css, linux, command, rpm

I am lookign out for an RPM where an html can be converted to image.So is there any rpm like html2image for RHEL5
or can the convert command do this

```
   convert a.html a.jpg
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quick search gaved this: http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/. Not sure about RPM, but there is a Debian package for it.

Comment: The link on the page just doesnt work svn co https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt

Comment: weird.
btw, there are some similar questions. Take a look, may be you'll find something that suits you http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=cutycapt